# How do I change the QGIS scalebar segment width units from mm to inches? I need the scalebar to print as 1 inch long

Tags: qgis

I've been struggling to print my scalebar segments at exactly 1 inch for several hours now. Changing the scalebar width to 25.4mm (1 inch) does not solve the issue; my scalebar segments consistently print a few millimeters short of an inch. I'm wondering if there's a way to force QGIS to register my segment widths in terms of inches instead of mm to troubleshoot this issue.

For context, my basemap orthoimage is in NAD83 North Carolina (ft-US). My map scale is "800". My scalebar units are in feet, label multiplier of 1.00. QGIS Version 3.30.2

[image]

Comment: If the length in mm is off then a length in inches would be too. I expect that your printer is rescaling something (a4 paper?)

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Units" scalebar property change the scalebar units to inches, if neccessary. Then go back to the Segments property, shown in your picture. Select Fixed Width (instead of Fit Segment Width). It will ask you how many units you want the fixed width of each segment to be, because you made the units inches, you can enter 1. If you continue to use the Fit Segment Width option, with the upper and lower bounds as you have them, if you move the map at all, they automatically resize (sometimes almost imperceptibly). The *only* units that you can enter values in for the upper and lower bounds is mm. See link to resource and direct quote below.

[image: location of units property menu]

I used the QGIS documentation located here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_scale_bar.html

Summary:
"Set how long a segment will be in your scale bar units (Fixed width)

Or limit the total scale bar size in mm with Fit segment width option. In the latter case, each time the map scale changes, the scale bar is resized (and its label updated) to fit between the upper and lower range set."